# SQL Error 1452 only occurs when Inserting row from PHP page using auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

EDIT: I tried an INSERT INTO from PhpMyAdmin. I noticed If I just do the GenreName and dont put an ID, the AutoIncrement is giving me a row ID of 2147483647 :
    INSERT INTO Genres( GenreName ) 
    VALUES ('testFromPhpmyAdmin')

I got an error like this before when working directly in the MySQL database, but everything I tried from that past error on this new one is not working. I have exhausted as many StackOverflow posts about this as I could but none of the solutions ended up working. I have definitely checked that the ID is available in both of the tables. Also, it worked when I had the page simply have a form with text inputs for AlbumID and AlbumName, but I wanted to get rid of text entry for AlbumID as its autoincremented in the MySQL DB so users should not have to type/guess a new ID.

Error: SQL Error: 
Errno: 1452
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`andrew79_601`.`Albums`, CONSTRAINT `Albums_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ArtistID`) REFERENCES `Artists` (`ArtistID`))

This happens when Im on on my addalbum.php page.
This is the code I'm using:
*addalbum.php*

```
<?php 

//Get All genre
include 'dbconnect.php';
$sql_genre = "SELECT GenreID FROM Genres";
$genre_data = $mysqli->query($sql_genre);

// Get all artists
$sql_artist = "SELECT ArtistID FROM Artists";
$artists_data = $mysqli->query($sql_artist);

?>

<form action="addalbumssrv.php" method="post">

<!-- AlbumID:<input type="text" name="AlbumID" id="AlbumID"/></br> -->
Album Name:<input type="text" name="AlbumName" id="AlbumName"/></br>
    <div>                    
                        <div class="dev-left">Genre ID:&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="dev-left">
                            <?php if ($genre_data->num_rows > 0) { ?>
                                <select name="genre" style="width: 150px;">
                                    <option value="">------Select-------</option>
                                    <?php while ($row = $genre_data->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $row['GenreID']; ?>
                                        </option>
                                    <?php }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <?php
                            } else {
                                echo 'No Genre ID Found';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <!--Artist drop down-->
                    <div>                    
                        <div class="dev-left">Artist ID:&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="dev-left">
                            <?php if ($artists_data->num_rows > 0) { ?>
                                <select name="artist" style="width: 150px;">
                                    <option value="">------Select-------</option>
                                    <?php while ($row = $artists_data->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $row['ArtistID']; ?>
                                        </option>
                                    <?php }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <?php
                            } else {
                                echo 'No Artist ID Found';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

*addalbumssrv.php:*

```
<?php

//include 'dbconnect.php';

$link = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'andrew79_601', 'csis601', 'andrew79_601');
if ($link->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error: Failed to make a MySQL connection, here is why: </br>";
    echo "Errno: " . $link->connect_errno . "</br>";
    echo "Error: " . $link->connect_error . "</br>";

    exit;
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$AlbumID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['AlbumID']);
$AlbumName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['AlbumName']);



// attempt insert query execution
//$sql = "INSERT INTO Albums (AlbumID, AlbumName) VALUES ('$AlbumID', '$AlbumName')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO Albums (AlbumName) VALUES ('$AlbumName')";

if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: SQL Error: </br>";
    echo "Errno: " . $link->errno . "</br>";
    echo "Error: " . $link->error . "</br>";

    exit;
}
?>
<script>
window.location='albums.php';
</script>
```

Table structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/76JHg.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that an attempt was made to insert or update a row in the "Albums" table, and the value supplied for the "ArtistID" column was invalid.

The foreign key constraint is enforcing a rule:  the value in the "ArtistID" column *must match* a value in the "ArtistID" column of the "Artists" table.

artists

```
ArtistID  artist_name
--------  -----------
     112  Rush
```

albums

```
AlbumID  ... ArtistID ...
-------      --------
   2112           112
```

If we attempt to insert a row to "Albums"

```
INSERT INTO Albums (..., ArtistID ,...) VALUES (..., 707 ,...)
```

MySQL is going to check that the value `'707'` supplied for the "ArtistID" column appears in the "Artists" table.

When MySQL (InnoDB) doesn't find a row in "Albums" with a matching value in the "ArtistID" column, it will throw a foreign key constraint error.

That's what MySQL is reporting: there isn't a matching row in "Artists".

To fix this, the "INSERT INTO Albums" statement must supply a valid value for "ArtistID".

If the column allows for NULL values, we could insert a NULL. Then the album would not be related to an artist.

---

Given the statement shown in the code:

```
INSERT INTO Albums (AlbumName) VALUES ('something')
```

The "ArtistID" column must be defined with a DEFAULT value other than NULL, or there's a BEFORE INSERT trigger that is assigning a non-NULL value.

The statement should probably be like this:

```
INSERT INTO Albums (AlbumName,ArtistID) VALUES ('something',112)
                             ^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^
```

With a valid value supplied for the ArtistID column.